# How to pass filter-params with React?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm using [Semantic-React](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form#form-example-subcomponent-control) and I have component-filter which consists of checkbox groups. Every checkbox has id and I must pass them in order to filter the results.First idea was to perform method which would be called after checkbox `onCLick`(which would pass checkbox id). And in this method set in state an object and after every checkbox click change it. I remember, that in `Jquery` exists `$('form').serialize()` which everytime checks form elements and gets checked values automaticaly. Exists something like this in react, or semantic-ui react? I would be simplier to use such method than to create and control object in state

Answer (score 0):

You should use "controlled components":

1. Filter component should keep a set of checked ids as part of `state`.
2. Checkbox `checked` property should be set to `true` if the set contains box id (and to `false` otherwise) in Filter component `render`.
3. Checkbox `onChange` should be handled by filter component and modify state.
4. Filter can access it's `state` handling checkbox `onChange` or button "Apply" `onClick` (or any other event handled by Filter component).
5. Be careful: `setState` is an async function and directly reading other component `state` can lead to data race, so `state` must be read after proper event fired by React. Also there are a bunch of state-keepers like Redux.

It is described in official docs here: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html